# Java FX: How to create exact UI having psd template?

Tags: java, javafx-8, psd

Assume I got some psd-templates from graphic designers and my task is to create the exact UI implementation on Java FX, strictly following the all recomendations from the templates.

How can I do that?

I was searching around and found a [Java FX production suite](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/index-139218.html#10) from Oracle.
But it seems that this tool is dead.

Comment: Well, you can always position element with pixel precision, but would you really want to do that? What if the user's screen has different dimensions?

Comment: @Thomas might be define some proportions depend on screen size. I am rather wondering how to exact move some colors, fonts, controls sizes and so on i.e. make custom fx css from design template.